# Reasoning behind taking the Fourier transform of the fermionic operators for a circular $1$D spin chain

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, fermions, eigenvalue

In the section 4.1 of [Quantum Computation by Adiabatic Evolution](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0001106v1.pdf), Farhi et al proposes a quantum adiabatic algorithm to solve the $2$-SAT problem on a ring. To compute the complexity of the algorithm the authors computed the energy gap between the ground and first excited states of the 
adiabatic Hamiltonian.

The adiabatic Hamiltonian is defined as 
$$
\tilde{H} (s) = (1-s) \sum^n_{j=1}(1-\sigma^{(j)}_x) + s \sum^n_{j=1}\frac{1}{2} (1-\sigma^{(j)}_z \sigma^{(j+1)}_z )
$$

To prove the correctness of the algorithm, the authors consider an operator which negates the value of the bits in the $z$ axis.
$$
G = \prod^n_{j=1}\sigma^{(j)}_x
$$

Then the authors start the steps of Jordan-Wigner transformation. The fermionic operators are defined as follows.

$$
b_j = \sigma_x^1 \sigma_x^2 \ldots \sigma_x^{j-1} \sigma_-^{j} \mathbf{ 1}^{j+1} \ldots \mathbf{ 1}^n
\\
b^\dagger_j = \sigma_x^1 \sigma_x^2 \ldots \sigma_x^{j-1} \sigma_+^{j} \mathbf{ 1}^{j+1} \ldots \mathbf{ 1}^n
$$
where
$$
\sigma_{\pm} = \sigma_x \pm i \sigma_y
$$.

After reexpressing the adiabatic Hamiltonian using the fermionic operators the authors mention the following fact before taking the Fourier transform of the fermionic operators.

> Because this is invariant under the translation, $b_j \to b_{j+1}$ ,
>   and is quadratic in the $b_j$ and $b^\dagger_j$ , a transformation to
>   fermion operators associated with waves running round the ring will
>   achieve the desired reduction of $H(s)$.

**My questions:**

1. What reduction are the authors talking about?
2. Why do we need that reduction?
3. In the Fourier transform, $\beta_p =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum^n_{j=1} e^{i\pi p j/n} b_j$, why $p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)$?

**My attempt:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The reduction they are referring to is explain in the middle of page 13: "We now write (4.5) in the invariant sector as a sum of $n/2$ commuting $2×2$ Hamiltonians that we can diagonalize."

2) They are "reducing" the difficult problem of diagonalizing a very large matrix to the much easier problem of separately diagonalizing $n/2$ different $2 \times 2$ matrices.

3) At the very top of page 14, it says "Since we will restrict ourselves to the $G = 1$ sector, (4.10) and (4.11) are only consistent if $b_{n+1} = −b_1$, so we take this as the definition of $b_{n+1}$."  These are called *antiperiodic boundary conditions* and often occur when fermions are put on a periodic ring (either in real space, as in this case, or in imaginary time, as in the Matsubara formalism in statistical quantum field theory).  Only the odd values of $p$ are compatible with this antiperiodic boundary condition - even values of $p$ would result in a function with *periodic* boundary conditions.